# Storing A Facebook User's Game Data Game Maker

Tags: facebook, gml, game-maker

I've been trying to figure out how to store a user's data into a database without much knowledge or documentation and surprising enough there's a lot of problems coming up, so I was wondering if anyone know of some good guides on how to store game variables specific to a facebook users in game maker? So far I've been looking at using PHP but I can't figure out how to properly correlate it with Game Maker.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use PHP (or some other server sided language, like Node) to open up a webserver. You can then let Game Maker communicate over HTTP(S) with that service.

You will need to do that if you're using Facebook anyway.